# Why do stylesheets influence QTableWidget behaviour?

Tags: python, focus, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I use python2.7 and PyQt4. I created a simple app with a button-box and a table-widget. If I edit a table cell and press the Ok button, the cell editor always disappears. But after I add the `app.setStyleSheet(s)` line, the cell editor does not disappear after the OK button is pressed. What is going on?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        table = QtGui.QTableWidget()

        table.setColumnCount(3)
        table.setRowCount(5)

        l.addWidget(table)

        l.addWidget(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    s = "QWidget{background:red;}"
    # app.setStyleSheet(s)
    app.setStyleSheet(s)

    mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    w = Widget()
    mw.setCentralWidget(w)
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Qt4, but I can't find a specific report for it. The same code works as expected when using PyQt5, so it somehow got fixed at some point.

The bug is actually in `QDialogButtonBox` rather than `QTableWidget`. If you add a `QLineEdit` to the example and set focus on it, you will see that clicking on the Ok button does not switch focus. Or to be more precise, clicking on the *first* button does not switch focus. All the other buttons in the button-box work normally.

I thought that this might have something to do with the [default](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) and/or [autoDefault](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html#autoDefault-prop) properties, because they usually change the way buttons are styled (e.g. a highlighted border). But setting the properties doesn't have any effect - the bug really does seem to affect just the *first* button.